# why is this referring to window object?

Tags: javascript

```
   var x = 5,
    o = {
        x: 10,
        doIt: function doIt(){
            var x = 20;
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert(this.x);
            }, 10);
        }
    };
o.doIt();
```

Why is this referring to `window object rather than o`. I am inside the `object o` context, so it should print me 10 right?

Comment: you can access variable x directly.

Comment: It is referring to `window` is because it is inside `function(){}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = 5,
    o = {
        x: 10,
        doIt: function doIt(){
            var x = 20;
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert(this.x);
            }, 10);
        }
    };
o.doIt();
```

All functions passed into `setTimeout()` are executed in the `global scope`. The value is 5 because this.x is the same as window.x

Answer (score 4):

The anonymous function is executed after 10ms, and the execution context is not in `o` at that time.

Check out the answers to [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

To make this alert 20, change `this.x` to simply `x`.

Comment: PS: To make it alert 10, `o.x`.